# Python Nested If Then statement not seen in while loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement, nested

I am developing a menu application (CLI) and when user selects a number choice from the menu then the app does something different for each choice. But first I want to make sure they enter a valid number then do something. If not a valid number, then loop through menu. If number 9 is selected, exit the application. The problem is it doesn't seem to recognize my nested if then condition statements. It just sees the first if then condition and then loops through menu again without "doing something". How do I get it to recognize the nested if thens?

```
import datetime
import os
import pyfiglet

def main():
    Banner()
    menu()


def menu():
    choice =int('0')
    while choice !=int('9'):
        print("1. Show the banner again")
        print("2. View just a selected date range")
        print("3. Select a date range and show highest temperature")
        print("4. Select a date range and show lowest temperature")
        print("5. Select a data range and show the highest rainfall")
        print("6. Make a silly noise")
        print("7. See this menu again")
        print("9. QUIT the program")

        choice = input ("Please make a choice: ")

        if choice.isdigit():
          print(int(choice))
          if choice == 1:
            result = pyfiglet.figlet_format("P y t h o n  R o c k s", font = "3-d" )
            print(result)
          elif choice == 2:
            getWeather()
            choice == 0
          elif choice == 3:
            print("Do Something 3")
          elif choice == 4:
            print("Do Something 4")
          elif choice == 5:
            print("Do Something 5")
          elif choice == 6:
            os.system( "say burp burp burp burpeeeeee. I love love love this menu application")
          elif choice == 7:
            print("Do Something 7")
          elif choice == 8:
            print("Do Something 8")
          elif choice == 9:
            print("***********************************************************************")
            print("Goodbye! Program exiting.....")
            print("***********************************************************************")
            exit()
        else:
          print("Your choice is not an integer. Please try again")
          print("")
          continue

def Banner():
  result = pyfiglet.figlet_format("P y t h o n  R o c k s", font = "3-d" )
  print(result)

def getWeather():
  weatherdata1 = print(input("What date would you like to start your weather data query with? Please    enter the date in this format YYYYMMDD"))
  weatherdata2 = print(input("What date would you like to end your weather data query with? Please enter the date in this format YYYYMMDD"))
  print(weatherdata1)
  print(weatherdata2)


main()
```

Comment: choice is a string and your comparing it to a number so they will never be `True` your essentially doing `"3" == 3`. You should convert choice to an int when you read the input `choice = int(input ("Please make a choice: "))`

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your input to `int` like so:

`choice = int(input ("Please make a choice: "))`

or, you need to convert the choice to `int` when comparing. Like so:

```
if int(choice) == 1:
    result = pyfiglet.figlet_format("P y t h o n  R o c k s", font = "3-d" )
    print(result)
elif int(choice) == 2:
    getWeather()
    choice == 0
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes it is the simple things that trip me up.